# Tools to convert source code to EPUB/HTML

Tags: html, source-code, plain-text, epub, kindle

I like to read source code on my Kindle, and thus I need to convert it to either epub or HTML.

I want the result to preferably have syntax highlighting and auto detection of source language. If not, even a tool to convert plain text to EPUB is enough.

Other requirements: CLI-based, unix

The best solution I have found thus far:

```` pandoc -s -f markdown <(ec '```python') *.py <(ec '```') -o a.epub ````

Comment: Have a look at doxygen, here you get the documentation and also the possibility to display the source code. Only thing is that you didn't specify your source language, so not sure if the source language is supported.